# Passing optional parameters to subroutines without instantiating them

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

I have a script that prompts the user for input (web address, username and password, etc.) and validates those inputs or prompts the user again.

Now I want to be able to call this script while also supplying some of these parameters on the command-line, by having them as optional parameters, and passing them to the original subroutines. However, in the scope of the script I can test whether or not the parameters were supplied with `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('a')`, but once I pass the parameter `$a` (which might not have been supplied) to a function, the same test will always return `$True`.

**Sample code:**

```
function main {
    param (
        [string]$a
    )
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('a')) {
        "main - a is $a"
    }
    else {
        "main - didn't get a"
    }
    getStr $a
}

function getStr {
    param (
        [string]$a
    )
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('a')) {
        "getStr - a is $a"
    }
    else {
        "getStr - didn't get a"
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
main

main "hello"
```

**Expected output:**

```
main - didn't get a
getStr - didn't get a

main - a is hello
getStr - a is hello
```

**Actual output:**

```
main - didn't get a
getStr - a is

main - a is hello
getStr - a is hello
```

My guess is that `$a` is instantiated when calling `getStr $a`, is there a more elegant/correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@PSBoundParameters`. I modified your functions so I could run this as a script.

**Code**

```
param (
    [string]$a
)

function main {
    param (
        [string]$a
    )
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('a')) {
        "main - a is $a"
    }
    else {
        "main - didn't get a"
    }
    getStr @PSBoundParameters
}

function getStr {
    param (
        [string]$a
    )
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('a')) {
        "getStr - a is $a"
    }
    else {
        "getStr - didn't get a"
    }
}
main @PSBoundParameters
```

**Output**

```
PS C:\> .\code.ps1 -a string
main - a is string
getStr - a is string
PS C:\> .\code.ps1
main - didn't get a
getStr - didn't get a
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the question as stated. If I may - what about the case where I might get several parameters, where each subroutine only needs to check one?

Comment: For future reference - tested this myself, I just send the splatted (`@`) `PSBoundVariables` to each function, which checks for the key it wants.